# Image not Found using PIL and Urllib to retrieve URL

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, python-imaging-library, urllib

I keep receiving the following error no matter what image url I try to use:

```
line 76, in <module>
    radar = Label(root, image = im)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2556, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2055, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
TclError: image "<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=538x190 at 0x105D4A830>" doesn't exist
```

Here is a snippet of code:

```
    import pywapi, pprint, string, urllib, io
    from Tkinter import *
    from PIL import Image, ImageTk

    fd = urllib.urlopen("http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png")
    imgFile = io.BytesIO(fd.read())
    im = Image.open(imgFile)
    image = Label(root, image = im)
    image.grid(row = 7, column = 1)
```

I believe using a Label requires a PhotoImage and I am unsure of how to best proceed. Thank you.

Comment: So have you tried using PhotoImage?

Comment: yes,  no luck though. `KeyError: <_io.BytesIO object at 0x103e85a10>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me the following code works. Please check if you do same:

```
import urllib, io

from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


root = Tk()

fd = urllib.urlopen("http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png")
imgFile = io.BytesIO(fd.read())
im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(imgFile)) # <-- here
image = Label(root, image = im)
image.grid(row = 7, column = 1)

root.mainloop()
```

Basically, I added PhotoImage and pass this to Label. Also check if you have zlib. Pillow does not read png by itself. It relays on [external libraries](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#external-libraries).

[image]